# Google visualization api grouped column chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to create a column chart but at the same time I want to have some columns grouped into specific sections or draw a vertical line after a specific group or number of columns, like so:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to

Comment: there are no standard [options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) for lines / borders within the hAxis section -- you could possibly build your own -- or try to modify the chart once it has drawn -- you can use `bar.groupWidth` to group the columns...